# Bootstrap 4 - DropDown menu - Element is over navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have problem with DropDown menu. When I'm trying to add padding to DropDown menu (class - drop_link) It pushes whole element over `<nav>`. I don't really know how stop this from happening. I tried turn off some attributes from browser, but It didn't do anything.

Here is my attempt: [Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqxPrv)

Comment: you want dropdown below to your navbar?

Comment: post your code here, edit the question and add it

Comment: Yap. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: @mlegg I don't think that I can do that for full understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following styles to your `<a>` element inside your "dropdown" div.

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

And, remove "margin-left: 3px;" from your "dropdown" div.

This is only one between many possible solutions.

cheers